# Webclient returing null

Tags: spring-boot, webclient, reactive

I have 2 SpringCloudStream applications which are producer and consumer over Kafka. The Kafka Consumer application receives the message ,calls DB and Webclient to receive some info and returns the updated object. In the below code which is for the consumer, the WebClient call is not updating the object and returning null for the field but the DB call is fine.
The service by itself is running fine.
Kindly suggest what I am missing here.

```
@Service
public class BookService {

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Autowired
    private WebClient webClient;

    public Book updateBook(Book book) {
        book.setBookName(book.getBookName().toUpperCase());
        bookRepository.findById(book.getId()).ifPresent(book1 -> {
            book.setBookIsbn(book1.getBookIsbn()); //getting set
        });

        webClient
                .method(HttpMethod.GET)
                .uri("http://localhost:9898/rx/getBookDetails/" + book.getId())
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.ALL)
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, response -> Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Exception :: " + response)))
                .bodyToMono(Book.class)
                .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(3, Duration.ofSeconds(1)))
                .onErrorResume(error -> Mono.just(new Book()))
                .map(book1 -> {
                    book.setAuthorId(book1.getAuthorId()); //authorId = null
                    return book;
                });

        System.out.println("Book processed successfully...");
        return book;
}
}
```

Comment: I don't know about `Mono`, but this line `.onErrorResume(error -> Mono.just(new Book()))` seems to suggest that even if there was an error, return an empty `Book`. So, are you sure that there was no error in the response?

Comment: `WebClient` is reactive and you only define a stream of events, you aren't actually subscribing to it, and thus it doesn't do anything.

Comment: You are never doing anything with the return value of `webClient`

Comment: Right...I added   .subscribe(); at the end but still it is null

Comment: @astar subscribe is null? I doubt that, because it returns a subscription.

Comment: Mono<Book> bookMono = webClient
                .method(HttpMethod.GET)
                .uri("http://localhost:9898/rx/getBookDetails/" + book.getId())
                .bodyToMono(Book.class);
                
        bookMono.subscribe(book1 -> book.setAuthorId(book1.getAuthorId()));